# How can I get a list of unbound keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for keyboard shortcuts and cords that aren't bound to anything in Visual Studio 2008. I'd settle for an über list on the net somewhere or even a macro or tool that might spit them out. I'm mainly interested in finding keys to use for cords but with Visual Studio's default key bindings and Resharper's additional bindings the choices look few and far between. My goal is to introduce some sort of consistency to new bindings that belong to a group of functions.

**Update**: Currently poking at a solution and should have something soon. If anyone is curious, there are **a lot** of unused keyboard shortcuts. Resharper's shortcuts is also included in Jeff Atwood's macro referred to in Cypher2100's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112405/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-unbound-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio-2008/1116457#1116457).

Comment: This is the list of VS's unbound keyboard shortcuts:

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will get Resharper's shortcuts, but this macro will get the list of all VS2008 shortcuts: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000412.html (it works for 2008, just make sure to follow the directions, the references are important).

If you copy the output into a text document, you'll get something that could easily be reduced to just the used bindings. While it isn't exactly what you wanted (a list of all *un*used bindings), if you wrote something to generate all the bindings you were considering and removed all the used ones, you'd have what you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll take a look when I have some time.

Comment: This is a great link. Thanks for pointing us to the original source.

Comment: The link is broken, but I could really use something like this for 2017.